# JQuery Mobile: Performance Issue with $mobile.changePage()

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery Mobile 1.1.1 and having performance issues when running the app on an iPad. I have two pages which are loaded via a navbar and both have a large amount of input fields - about 200. Toggling between the pages takes more than 6 seconds.

Using a js profiler on windows I tracked down where most time is spent and found it's in $.mobile.changePage() / enchancePage() / each / _createWidget(). So it seems the JQM widget transformation is taking the most time.

I tried turning on JQM caching and prefetching (see below) but it does not seem to make a difference. Does anyone know why or what else could be done to improve performance?

Thanks!

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.defaultTransition = 'none';
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
        $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false; 
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
    });
</script>

    <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page-1.htm" data-ajax="false" rel="external">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page-2.htm" data-ajax="false" rel="external" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div

<div id="Page1" data-dom-cache="true">
...
<div id="Page2" data-dom-cache="true">
...
```

Comment: `mobileinit` code should be placed in `head` after loading jQuery and before loading jQuery Mobile scripts.

Comment: why are you not using ajax ? you know if you have one page app in jquery mobile it must use ajax, what are you doing now is destroying current page and parsing the next one, and back and forth like that